# Email links in Yahoo mail removing href attribute and live.com adding https

Tags: php, email, hyperlink, windows-live, yahoo-mail

Facing an issue with the email URL's on my application.I send users the links for sharing files via email.The links is to login page on my application,which authenticates the user.Now the link in emails **behaves different in different mail providers**.Google does it in the right way i.e my link appears and works fine in google.
Yahoo the worst of all.It completely strips the `href` attribute from the link.This is after inspecting the link in firebug console.

```
<a style="color:#333;padding-left:3px;padding-right:10px;text-decoration:none;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;font-size:10pt;" rel="nofollow" id="yui_3_13_0_1_1396955520023_2240">links.txt</a>
```

It adds the `rel=nofollow` which may be causing the issue.But I have no idea why this happens,went through web but found others facing same problem with no solution that works.
My link is something like this `http://www.abc.com/authenticate.php?id=YLZr4Sj3MjAxNw==&pid=K4mfnbCyMQ==&auth=Iu8Yi2er`
This does not have any special character that may cause the issue.

Live.com : This adds a `https://` protocol to the link instead of `http://` The link I build is with `http`,but it internally adds `https` to it which I don't want.

Any one who has faced similar issues,I would like some inputs,guidance on the issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you aren't missing the `http://` protocol-prefix. Your `<a>` tag should be in this format:
`<a href="http://www.abc.com">abc.com</a>`

I used your link. Yahoo mail does not have any problem with it.

Comment: The links are added dynamically to mail and the email strips of the href attribute as I mentioned.Static links do work fine.

Comment: Did you ever come right with this problem? I am facing a similar predicament right now.

Comment: Yes @Archie22is. My problem solved with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. I came right with the following set of html in my code:

```
 # send the email to Applicant
$to = $application['myemail'];
$subject = 'Mentorship Registration Form';
$headers = "From: xxx@domain.com " . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".  $application['myemail'] . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: zzz@domain.co.za, ccc@domain.co.za\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title></title>
            <style></style>
        </head>
        <body>';
$message .= '<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="color:#FFFFFF;background:#b4b4b4;padding:5px 0 0 0;">
        <tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue then i just used `stripslashes()` with the email body and it worked perfectly fine

```
$body= stripslashes($mail_message);
```

Comment: What is `stripslashes()` ?